# RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding Decryption in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

Here's java code
z.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.util.Base64;

public class z {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        try 
        {
            String public_key = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC32VkPYUKYszF665DH0jRuCuyKPqf4pkmcUWXOp8CZkNriew18iLiNGBAtDXhmtdzj6bEaBbxkNixzLfNMtNQw53bfW5lgRC91nG4fiK085sJ8CkdL22PIhRWO75x2pwk+Wqlx5N3OxVV0oS76dI7/pCqTCfqJec7BMH820Im5AwIDAQAB";
            String encrpted_data_base64 = "qKVan83WWFmVRVASPZ2Io8iM1qs/rowwHH4zh7NNcrh8544hhJr1fKE2PkogAKZWD8mjoO1x4AhRSkrLMsTB0m6V+ZsayLOLiIpCh5hsybaH3NdPKPhMyIqAUdw3au2Zcl76b/4FeNvP9ay/S0niXzQMVBTgHcHhrfjquqQnoXc=";
            
            PublicKey generatePublic = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(public_key.getBytes())));
            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            instance.init(2, generatePublic);
            byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrpted_data_base64.getBytes());
            byte[] bArr = instance.doFinal(decode);
            String s = new String(bArr);
            System.out.println(s);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

run it and it will output the result "rtmp://wfjsh.sryhm.cn/5showcam/7362473_1636710891?auth_key=1636719851-0-0-85e0853c941754dff7809599215a6076"

But how can I decrypt this enceypted data in Python3?
Here's my python3 code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64decode
from base64 import b64encode

public_key = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC32VkPYUKYszF665DH0jRuCuyKPqf4pkmcUWXOp8CZkNriew18iLiNGBAtDXhmtdzj6bEaBbxkNixzLfNMtNQw53bfW5lgRC91nG4fiK085sJ8CkdL22PIhRWO75x2pwk+Wqlx5N3OxVV0oS76dI7/pCqTCfqJec7BMH820Im5AwIDAQAB"
encrpted_data_base64 = "qKVan83WWFmVRVASPZ2Io8iM1qs/rowwHH4zh7NNcrh8544hhJr1fKE2PkogAKZWD8mjoO1x4AhRSkrLMsTB0m6V+ZsayLOLiIpCh5hsybaH3NdPKPhMyIqAUdw3au2Zcl76b/4FeNvP9ay/S0niXzQMVBTgHcHhrfjquqQnoXc="

public_key = b64decode(public_key)
public_key = RSA.importKey(public_key)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(public_key)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt(b64decode(encrpted_data_base64), "Error while decrypting")
print(plaintext)
```

Run it and it throws these:

```
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(b64decode(encrpted_data_base64), "Error while decrypting")
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py", line 169, in decrypt
    m_int = self._key._decrypt(ct_int)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 156, in _decrypt
    raise TypeError("This is not a private key")
TypeError: This is not a private key
```

I am not sure what's wrong

Comment: PyCryptodome does not support decryption with the public key. Java/JCE, however, allows it as part of a low level verification process. So for Python you have to find a library with corresponding functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You Can't Decrypt using the public key.